# Using several key aliases with Android Maven Plugin and Jarsigner

Tags: android, maven, jarsigner

I'm newbie on Maven and I would need to set up a testing project for a complete Android device using Robotium, Android Maven plugin & Jarsigner.

In order to successfully deploy, install & run the tests on device, they would need to be signed using the same private keys the native apps (Eg. Contacts, Messaging, Camera...) on the device are using. Since there are several different keys, and it seems that the key aliases are defined in pom.xml-files (only one in each file in jarsigner configuration?), do I need to have multiple pom's defined in my project, or can they be defined elsewhere? The approach using multiple poms sounds hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the morseflash example on how to set up signing. I am not sure I understand your question in terms of multiple keys and the native apps. You have to use your own key for your own app. And that is completely independent of any other app.